# AWS resource naming constraints

Tags: amazon-web-services

is there a comprehensive list, at least for the most, let's say, 50 common AWS services and related resources, that list all the maximum length for the "Name" attribute?

Most resources uses only tags to define Name attribute, but others have a separate Name that doesn't follow the tag rules (e.g. Lambda functions can have a max name length of 140 chars, RDS Instances 63, S3 bucket 63, and so on...)

I tried hard to search the documentation with no luck, apart from having to open and search doc for each and every resource.

Also a python script would work, but also there I didn't have luck on finding if the rigth api exists.

Could you please help?

Thanks

W.

Comment: Not aware of a canonical source, but just trying to think laterally about this for a moment. It might be worth reviewing what's available in the service definition files in the botocore GitHub repo (typically called service-2.json afaik). Another, possibly crazy, idea might be to call the relevant 'CreateXYZ' API but supply a name that's definitely too long (say 1024) to see what you get in the error response. Probably a  long shot though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single comprehensive list of all AWS services and their name limitations. It's on a service-by-service basis, so you'll have to review the constraints for each service that you're working with.